# jquery post method with MVC5

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".categories").click(function () {
        console.log("pre post");
        $.post('Index/Home/' + $(this).attr('data-id'), function (data) {
            console.log("category post success");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this codesnippet? :-/

My routes Work perfect.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url to post is wrong. you have written actionname before controller name it should be Home/Index like this-

```
 $(".categories").click(function () {
            console.log("pre post");
            $.post('Home/Index/' + $(this).attr('data-id'), function (data) {
                console.log("category post success");
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Just made my day! :-D

Don't know why i didn't see that! -.-